# Click on any link, redirect url to apache's port on varnish nginx apache2 stack

Tags: apache, url, redirect, nginx, varnish

I have set up a server with Varnish at port 80, nginx at port 8081 and apache2 at 81. Varnish uses nginx in backend, nginx does a reverse proxy for apache2.

So when I click on www.domain_name.com/index.php, it works fine and shows URL in same format. But if i click on any link present on the page, link changes from http://www.domain_name.com/mydata/server.php to http://www.domain_name.com:81/mydata/server.php.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue. I have tried a lot from wiki and google.
Thank in advance.

Comment: show us your proxy configuration in nginx

Answer (score 0):

try to clear your browsers cache